# Automate deployment of JSON map

Tags: azure, liquid, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App in Azure which use a Liquid map, to transform JSON content. I am trying to deploy the map using [New-AzureRmIntegrationAccountMap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.logicapp/new-azurermintegrationaccountmap) commandlet and the [Set-AzureRmIntegrationAccountMap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.logicapp/set-azurermintegrationaccountmap) commandlet.

I get the following error when calling the `Set-AzureRmIntegrationAccountMap` commandlet:

> Set-AzureRmIntegrationAccountMap : Unable to deserialize the response.

With this script:

```
Try
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Creating $baseName..."
    $mapContent = Get-Content -Path $fullName | Out-String

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "$mapContent"

    New-AzureRmIntegrationAccountMap -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $iacName -MapName $baseName -MapDefinition $mapContent -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Successfully created $baseName"
}
Catch
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Error creating $baseName, trying update..."
    Set-AzureRmIntegrationAccountMap -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $iacName -MapName $baseName -MapDefinition $mapContent -Force
    if ($?) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Successfully updated $baseName"
    } else {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Error updating $baseName"
        exit 1
    }
}
```

After some searches, the two commandlets accept the `MapType` parameter, but only one value is allowed (XSLT).

Is there a way to automate the deployment of Liquid maps in an integration account in Azure (powershell, ARM template...) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to automate the deployment of Liquid maps in an integration account in Azure (powershell, ARM template...) ?

Yes, I could create Liquid map with PowerShell on my side with the following code.

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
$IntegrationAccountName = "Integration Account name"
$ResouceGroupname = "ResourcegroupName" 
$ResourceLocation = "West US" # location
$ResourceName = "liquid name" 
$Content = Get-Content -Path "C:\Tom\simple.liquid" | Out-String
Write-Host $Content
$PropertiesObject = @{
    mapType = "liquid"
    content = "$Content"
    contentType = "text/plain"
}
New-AzureRmResource -Location $ResourceLocation -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName $ResouceGroupname -ResourceType Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/maps -ResourceName " $IntegrationAccountName/$ResourceName" -ApiVersion 2016-06-01 -Force
```

[image]

Check it from azure portal.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not able to test it today, but I will let you know at the beginning of the next week.