# How to upload liquid files in an integration account via powershell script or any other automated way?

Tags: azure, powershell, continuous-integration, azure-logic-apps

My liquid files are in git_hub repo and I want to upload liquid files in an integration account via powershell or cli

Answer (score 1):

I'm using "New-AzResource"

New-AzResource -Location $ResourceLocation -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName $ResouceGroupname -ResourceType Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/maps -ResourceName "$IntegrationAccountName/$ResourceName" -ApiVersion 2016-06-01 -Force

Answer (score 0):

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
$IntegrationAccountName = "Integration Account name"
$ResouceGroupname = "ResourcegroupName" 
$ResourceLocation = "westus" # location
$ResourceName = "liquid name" 
$Content = Get-Content -Path "C:\Tom\simple.liquid" | Out-String
Write-Host $Content
$PropertiesObject = @{
    mapType = "liquid"
    content = "$Content"
    contentType = "text/plain"
}
New-AzureRmResource -Location $ResourceLocation -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName $ResouceGroupname -ResourceType Microsoft.Logic/integrationAccounts/maps -ResourceName " $IntegrationAccountName/$ResourceName" -ApiVersion 2016-06-01 -Force
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49063466/1384539

Comment: Hi @thiago

Thanks for reply , I tried the same but I'm getting below error

##[error]Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Location'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

Comment: use Get-AzureRmLocation and try a different value.